# Could not write file ink_sparkle.frag

Tags: flutter

Could not write file to `C:\\Users\\vicsw\\Desktop\\sa\\assd\\Mobile app\\user app\\assd_user_flutter\\build\\app\\intermediates\\flutter\\debug\\flutter_assets\\shaders/ink_sparkle.frag`

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.20'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()

    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when you cannot write in the folder where Flutter SDK is located. When installing a new package to your Flutter project, but Flutter couldn't save the downloaded package, this error may occur. Or in other write cases. See the solution:

> You may have disabled unauthorized changes to protect the folder from
> ransomware. To allow it, go to Windows Security=>Virus & threat
> protection=>Manage settings=>Controlled folder access=>Turn off
> Controlled folder access.

Answer (score 1):

```
flutter upgrade
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter build appbundle
```

Solved the issue for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I also face a similar error. You just have to focus on 2 points, I hope your error will also be resolved:

1. Just remove space in the name and path of the app if any
2. Reduce the path, it should not be too long.

After these two steps, your error will be resolved.