# Why is permission error occurs? Could not write file to \build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug\flutter_assets\shaders/ink_sparkle.frag.spirv

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to run a flutter app but got error could not write file ink_sparkle.frag.spirv I suppose its a permission error, I opened Android studio in administrative mode. I disabled controlled folder access in windows 10. I searched on many places about this error and apply many methods but no one work for me. For example [this stackoverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75137803/could-not-write-file-ink-sparkle-frag) and [this github solution](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/120757). Both are not applicable in my case. Flutter Version is:

```
Flutter 3.16.3 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision b0366e0a3f (7 days ago) • 2023-12-05 19:46:39 -0800
Engine • revision 54a7145303                                            
Tools • Dart 3.2.3 • DevTools 2.28.4
```

I got this error.

```
Could not write file to F:\Company\SarmadEngineeringSolutions\Projects\ResturantSoftware\RestaurantStandardSoftware\foodie-multiple-restaurant-delivery-flutter\Foodie_V5.2.1_Source_Code\foodie-5.2\Foodie_Customer\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug\flutter_assets\shaders/ink_sparkle.frag.spirv

Target debug_android_application failed: ShaderCompilerException: Shader compilation of "E:\dev\flutter\packages\flutter\lib\src\material\shaders\ink_sparkle.frag" to "F:\Company\SarmadEngineeringSolutions\Projects\ResturantSoftware\RestaurantStandardSoftware\foodie-multiple-restaurant-delivery-flutter\Foodie_V5.2.1_Source_Code\foodie-5.2\Foodie_Customer\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug\flutter_assets\shaders/ink_sparkle.frag" failed with exit code 1.
impellerc stdout:

impellerc stderr:
Could not write file to F:\Company\SarmadEngineeringSolutions\Projects\ResturantSoftware\RestaurantStandardSoftware\foodie-multiple-restaurant-delivery-flutter\Foodie_V5.2.1_Source_Code\foodie-5.2\Foodie_Customer\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug\flutter_assets\shaders/ink_sparkle.frag.spirv





FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'E:\dev\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\src\main\groovy\flutter.groovy' line: 1350

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'E:\dev\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 19s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Now I need your expert suggestion to resolve this error. Looking forward to your kind reply.

Answer (score 0):

flutter clean.
then run the project again.

or delete the build fold generated and then run project again.